# Value of type 'some View' has no member 'badge'

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, badge, tabview

I'm unable to use a property `badge` in a `tabview` as xCode complains:

> *Value of type 'some View' has no member 'badge'*

.

```
var body: some View {
      TabView {
          Text("Your home screen here")
             .tabItem {
                 Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
              }
              .badge(5)
      }
 }
```

Comment: Works fine here with Xcode 13 / iOS 15. Which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: xcode 12.5 / iOS 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available only starting with iOS 15, and can be built starting with Xcode 13

See availability in SwiftUI declaration:

[image: demo]